# How to define EventStop timeStamp based on condition using tSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to figure out the following:

- I have a list of timestamps refering to the corresponding machine
  state (1 or 0)
- I am interested in generating a new table where:the first timestamp a machine jumps to machine state 1 (START) and the timestamp a machine breaks down (machinestate = 0, reasonID = 15) (END)

image 1

[image]

image 2
[image]

Comment: Looks like you'll need LAG/LEAD for this. MIN/MAX most likely won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical gaps-and-islands problem, where you intend to group together consecutive rows that have the same state.

Here is one way to solve it using the difference between the row numbers.

```
select
    equipment_id,
    min(timestamp) event_start,
    max(timestamp) event_stop,
    machine_state_id,
    max(reason_id) reason_id
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by equipment_id order by timestamp) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by equipment_id, machine_state_id order by timestamp) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by equipment_id, machine_state_id, rn1 - rn2
order by equipment_id, event_start
```